# Conditional navigation is not working after reload in react native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I have implemented conditional navigation, which is an alternative to switch navigation in react-navigation 5.

```
 <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontFamily: 'SFUIDisplay-Regular.otf',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#3e94f0',
        },
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
      }}
      initialRouteName="login">
      {loginState || isTokenExists ? (
        <Stack.Screen
          name="taskmanager"
          component={Main}
          options={{
            title: 'Task Manager',
            cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS,
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="login"
            component={Login}
            options={{
              title: 'Sign In',
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="register"
            component={Register}
            options={{
              title: 'Register',
              cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS,
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="forgetpassword"
            component={ForgetPassword}
            options={{
              title: 'Forgot Password',
              cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS,
            }}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

On logout, the loginStatus is setting false, and the token is cleared. I have taken uid as token

```
 //logout handler
  const logoutHandler = () => {
    console.log('AT logoutHandler', status);
    storeData('clearUID');
    dispatch(actions.loginStatus('', false));
    lowerOptionsToggle();
  };
```

Now the problem is logout functionality is working fine but if I'm reloading the app while the user is logged in, it's not logging out means the conditional navigation is not working.

Comment: make sure the value in the `loginState` || `isTokenExists` changes! or else it won't switch.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing/removing the loginstatus and token with AsyncStorage and apply conditional navigation accordingly. Also try applying the condition for initialRouteName as well.